# Unity: How To Limit Line Renderer Vertex Count

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to draw lines with a certain max of vertices allowed before stopping. However, when I have the max vertices such as 20, if you draw fast the length of the line will be farther than if you drew more slowly. How would you limit the vertex count so the line will only draw a certain length before stopping?

```
public List<Vector3> linePoints;
LineRenderer line;
int lineLength = 20;
Vector3 touchPos;
bool touching = false;

void Awake ()
{
  line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
  linePoints = new List<Vector3>();

  line.SetVertexCount(0);
  line.SetWidth(0.3f, 0.3f);
  line.SetColors(Color.cyan, Color.cyan);

  line.useWorldSpace = true;
}

void Update ()
{
  if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
  {
    touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
    touchPos.z = 0;

    if (!touching)
    {
      line.SetVertexCount(0);
      linePoints.RemoveRange(0, linePoints.Count);
      line.SetColors(Color.cyan, Color.cyan);
      touching = true;
    }
    else
    {
      if (linePoints.Count <= lineLength)
      {
        if (!linePoints.Contains(touchPos))
        {
          linePoints.Add(touchPos);
          line.SetVertexCount(linePoints.Count);
          line.SetPosition((linePoints.Count - 1), (Vector3)linePoints[(linePoints.Count - 1)]);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        touching = false;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    touching = false;
  }
}
```

Line should render same length no matter how fast you draw.

Comment: Keep a running total of how long the line is so far (start at `0f`). Every time you add another vertex: **1.** Add the newly added length to the running total. **2.** Check the total and see if it went over the maximum length (e.g., `20f`). **3.** If it did, then **A.** Find out how far it exceeds the max. **B.** Shorten the last segment by that amount of length.

Comment: What if the line begins to spiral? Getting distance between the previous point and the new one wouldn't work. @Ruzihm

Comment: It's being added to the running total, which means you do `runningTotal += Vector2.Distance(lastPoint, currentPoint);` I don't understand how a spiral makes the logic any different unless I misunderstand what you mean by "length of the line"